# What is the meaning of "dehyphenate"?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence in  [The hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/op-ed/picking-sides-in-west-asia/article26333419.ece) which was:

Although this approach has allowed India to eschew involvement in regional
disputes and dehyphenate relations with regional rivals...

What is the meaning of dehyphenate? I couldn't find it in any dictionarie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an extended meaning only used in Indian English, with relation to Indian foreign affairs.

At one time India consider relations with "Israel-Palestine"  considering the region as one country. This word has a hyphen "-" and this was called a "hyphenated foreign policy.

A change to consider relations separately with "Israel" and with "Palestine" was called "de-hyphenation". The endorsing an independent policy towards these two rivals is called the [de-hyphenation in India’s foreign policy.](https://www.gktoday.in/gk/indias-de-hyphenated-foreign-policy-towards-israel-and-palestine/)

By extension, the formation of separate relations with two countries or groups engaged in a regional dispute is called "dehyphenation". It is an expression only found in Indian English.

Answer (score 0):

They are using a big word to suggest improving the communication ie making it (more) direct.

A hyphen is or can be used to join or link certain words when explaining things - so “dehyphenation” is used here to suggest a stronger link or improved level of communication....